# Programmatic and declarative Constraint declaration

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I'm currently validating my beans through this kind of code:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
validator.validateValue(class, propertyName, value);
```

My classes look like this:

```
public static interface Primitive {
    public Primitive setString(String s);

    @NotNull
    public String getString();
}
```

This is working fine so far. But it seems that it's not possible with plain hibernate validator to get the Constraint Definitions/Mapping from a given Class and to add additional constraints like described [here](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/06/whats-new-in-hibernate-validator-41.html). It looks like the constraint mapping is all manual, which I don't like todo. On the other side the BeanDescriptor  which I get with `Validator.getConstraintsForClass(class)` seems to be not usable with ConstraintMapping.

This is what I have in mind:

```
ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();

mapping
    .type(Order.class).getConstraints()/*reads the constraints declared on the Bean*/
        .property("customer", ElementType.FIELD)/*add additional constraints*/
            .constraint(NotNullDef.class);
Validator validator = Validation
    .byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
    .configure()
    .addMapping(mapping)
    .buildValidatorFactory()
    .getValidator();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmatic constraint API is already additive, meaning you don't need your suggested *getConstraints*. See also the Validator online docs - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api

> By default, constraints added via the fluent API are additive to
>   constraints configured via the standard configuration capabilities.
>   But it is also possible to ignore annotation and XML configured
>   constraints where required.